# How do I style a specific DOM path without an ID?

Tags: css

I'd like to change the color of the text of the "Remember me" checkbox in the following `navbar`.

I'm currently using an `id` in the css:

```
#rememberme {
    color: #fff;
}
```

But I'd like to, instead, specify the DOM path, but without changing other inline checkboxes color, so only this one.
How would I go about specifying this without an `id`, simply by the DOM path?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" height=30 width=41></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                        Menu <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Main Courses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Desserts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Specials</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lunch Buffet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Weekend Brunch</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                <li><a href="contactus.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
              <label class="checkbox-inline">
                <input type="checkbox" name="approve" value="">
                <p id="rememberme">Remember me</p>
              </label>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: In Chrome devtools, on the `Elements` tab, you can select an element, then right click and choose `Copy | Copy selector`, to get the fully-qualified selector to that element. You can then pick and choose starting with that selector, based on which tags and classes you think are minimally necessary to uniquely select the item, but also importantly will continue to work even when you move things around in your HTML.

Comment: Thank you @torazaburo, that's what I was looking for. Excuse a newbie... :)

Comment: @eran Updated my answer with a better solution

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a unique input, you can do like this, using the attribute selector `[attribute="value"]` and the next-sibling selector `+`, which will, in this case, target a `p` which is a direct sibling of an `input` having an attribute `name` with a value of `approve`, which is a child of an element having the class `navbar-form`

```
.navbar-form input[name="approve"] + p {
  color: red;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
.navbar-form input[name="approve"] + p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.png" height=30 width=41>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Menu <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Courses</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Desserts</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Drinks</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Specials</li>
            <li><a href="#">Lunch Buffet</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Weekend Brunch</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="approve" value="">
          <p id="rememberme">Remember me</p>
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If you change your markup, the above could easily break, so giving the targeted element a class would be much better

```
p.rememberme {
  color: red;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
p.rememberme {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo.png" height=30 width=41>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Menu <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Appetizers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Courses</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Desserts</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Drinks</a>
            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Specials</li>
            <li><a href="#">Lunch Buffet</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Weekend Brunch</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
          <input type="checkbox" name="approve" value="">
          <p class="rememberme">Remember me</p>
        </label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is an extremely brittle approach, likely to break the first time the HTML changes. The right question to ask the OP is what rules or logic he wants to apply, that won't break when the HTML changes, to identify the paragraph to be styled.

Comment: Thank you both. @torazaburo I want to maintain that checkboxes within `navbar`s will have that color setting.

Comment: @torazaburo Agree with you fully. Updated my answer with a note ... and made the rule somewhat more specific

Answer (score 0):

It should work with this combined selector:

```
form label:last-of-type p { color: #fff; }
```

Comment: There are essentially an infinite number of selectors which will select the `#rememberme` element. The question is, what is the rule or logic by which he wants to identify that element, which will continue to work in the face of changes to the HTML, such as, perhaps, a new `label` tab underneath the current one, which would cause your proposal to break.

Comment: I know, so you should have asked him.